# html form to edit php code

Tags: php, html, edit

I'm working on a project that allows users to edit PHP code in PHP file.

I have a PHP page that uses the mail function to send emails. I want to allow the user to change the message sent out (in the mail function).

I know how to re-write over a file but how to edit it, I'm not sure...

**So here's the mail function:**

```
$name=$_POST['userName'];

$emaily=$_POST['userEmail'];

$email = "$sponsor_email"; 


$subject = "the subject"; 


$message = "This is the message I want the user to be able to edit."; 

mail($email, $subject, $message, "From: $user-email");
```

Now I've got the $message var printed out on in the html form (so the users can see what will be changed but i don't know how I'd go about actually writing the code to change it on from submit.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Sorry guys....

I didnt explain the situation properly.

The php file with the mail function will not be used to send an email from that form. All i want the form to do is edit the php file basically. I don't want to send the email with this form, this is for users to edit the mail function. Hope thats more clear...

Comment: My idea is that you run the risk of creating an open spam relay on your server. You are asking what looks like a basic programming question which implies a lack of familiarity with the PHP documentation and the potential security risks involved in allowing users to alter files on your server. You should do some serious reading about PHP regarding security holes, templates, and database access.

Comment: Yes but the project i'm working on will not be on my server, it will be distributed to users for them to install onto their domains (abit like wordpress). The domain owner will be the only person who can edit the data, no one else. So in this case, it should be alright :)

Comment: `$email = "$sponsor_email"; ` - why not just `$email = $sponsor_email;`?

Comment: @thiefMaster, I wrote the code a while ago... I will fix it up when its almost ready to publish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your editing page, just do something like below:

```
$message = file_get_contents("path to message file");
echo "<textarea id=\"message\">".$message."</textarea>";
```

Then you can edit whatever the contents of the file were.

Might be better though if you used a database, and sanitized the user input - rather than saving everything to a file.

Comment: Yeah I've decided to use an SQL db instead. But thanks for the answer. It will be good for future reference. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the textarea in the form named "message", then do $message = $_POST['message'];

Comment: Sorry, I didnt explain the situation properly. The php file with the mail function will not be used to send an email from that form. All i want the form to do is edit the php file basically. What you suggested was  to just post it off to the mail function and let the mail function send the email. But i dont want to send the email with this form, this is for users to edit the mail function.

Answer (score 0):

create a PHP that read what is in the PHP file that contains code to be edited then print it out in a HTML textarea then make another file that will write that modified code in the PHP file that has the code(to be modified). You can use google find how to read and write in a file.